# History record which came earlier than recent

Tags: sql

I have certain ID_NUM which have transactions which have History record which came earlier than recent

Below is one example

[image]

```
ID_num  Create Datetime Start Datetime  Rank_num
1   1/1/19 5:28     NULL                  1
1   12/1/18 9:25    1/1/19 9:25      2
1   12/1/18 7:39    12/1/18 9:25    3
1   11/1/18 7:40    12/1/18 13:37   4
1   10/1/18 7:38    11/1/18 13:37   5
1   9/1/18 13:37    9/1/18 13:37    6
1   9/1/18 13:37    10/1/18 13:37   7
```

Here Rank#4 has a Start Datetime > Rank#3.

These incorrect records are set because of a system error and would like to identify how many such rows exists

I would like to list all ID_num's which have similar behaviour

Any suggestion would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`.  For instance:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(start_datetime) partition by (id_num order by ranknum) as prev_start_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where start_datetime < prev_start_datetime
```

Comment: Thank You, @Gordon Linoff for the quick response